# Storing multiple values in a byte

Tags: java

I am writing a file to store information about locations on a map, for example where an object would spawn.
I write an byte to the file and within the byte there would be x and y coordinates how would I parse them from the file

```
int typeData = stream.readByte();
int x = typeData >> 2;
int y = typeData & 3;
```

this is an example of what I'm wanting to achieve.
What I am not sure is what would I have to do in the writing process, for example

```
outStream.writeByte((x << 2) + (y | 3));
```

This is an example, this code has not been tested and is likely wrong.

Comment: With 2 bits the only possible values of `y` are 0, 1, 2 and 3.  Is that enough?  It is unclear why you feel you need to pack values into bit strings like this.  Memory and disk space are pretty cheap and allocating a whole `int` to both `x` and `y` shouldn't cause a problem.  You need to explain what problem you're _really_ trying to solve here.

Comment: Manipulating bytes is a practice from the assembler era. There is absolutely no need to do it today.

Comment: I only have the parser for some information from a file I'm trying to read and want to create a writer for it so I can save more information to that file, but would it be better to rewrite this?

Answer (score 1):

Beware that the byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. Therefore, values are from -128 to +127, included.

So you are right when computing the bitwise operations with int variables (x and y), like that: `(x << 2) + (y | 3)`. Then you can cast to a byte or let Java automatically cast the result, only at the final step when calling writeByte().

You certainly need more that 8 bits to store your coordinates. To access to binary data stored in your file, remember that the initial order of a byte buffer is always BIG_ENDIAN when using the standard Java java.nio.ByteBuffer API.

Comment: I get this out.writeByte((20 << 2) + (15 & 3));
        int data = dataIn.readByte();
        int x = (data >> 2);
        int y = (data >> 2 | 3);
        //Output X: 20 Y: 23 should be 20 and 15

Comment: Using 2 bits to store 15 is not possible. Use 4 bits: `(20<<4) + (15 & (1<<4 - 1))`.